# Does it ever make sense to set the font-size to 1em?

Tags: css

I'm reviewing a cascading stylesheet that was originally developed by an outside shop and then heavily-modified in-house. We are trying to optimize it a little bit to remove some of the special-cases and workarounds that have been thrown-in during the intervening time and I noticed something odd in many of the styles:

```
element {
  font-size:1em;
}
```

Here, `element` isn't literal; it's some arbitrary element name, class-name, etc.

I believe the following are true:

1. Unless otherwise specified, `font-size` inherits from the parent element
2. The current `font-size` can be expressed as `1em`, `1ex`, `1ch`, or `100%`

That means that `font-size:1em` is exactly the same thing as not specifying a font-size at all, right?

At the very top of the file, there is this definition:

```
*,* * {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

This also especially does nothing, but does it to all elements.

Without `font-size:1em`, I could see a potential problem: runaway font-size changes. If I have:

```
span.larger {
    font-size:larger;
}
```

Then this may grow the text quite a bit:

```
<span class="larger">
  This text is a little bigger
  <span>and bigger
      <span>and bigger</span>
  </span>
</span>
```

But it doesn't actually behave that way: the `font-size:larger` is only applied to the outer span and not to those inner spans. The *computed* font-size is inherited, not the *definition* of the font-size (which would lead to runaway *embiggening*.

I've used browser tools such as Firefox's inspector, Chrome's dev tools, etc. to disable these styles doesn't seem to change the way the pages look, but I haven't executed an exhaustive review of the whole site.

Am I missing something? Or can I simply remove all instances of

```
font-size:1em
```

?

***UPDATE***
I obviously missed what happens when you do something more complicated with font-size and nested elements:

```
div {
  font-size:1.5em;
}

<div>
  Bigger
  <div>
    and bigger
    <div>etc.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This causes runaway [embiggening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisa_the_Iconoclast#Embiggen_and_cromulent). It's a bit pathological, since defining all `div`s to be bigger than their parents is probably not what you want to do. But nested lists e.g. `ol ol ol` could certainly cause a problem.

So, is this kind of structure a prophylactic measure to prevent runaway font-size increases?

```
* * {
  font-size:1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess so.

Really if you want to keep all of your fonts consistent, I have seem people use `rem` which is based off the html font size, then you won't have your embiggenning issue.

In general I think it is considered *bad practice* to use `*` in css let alone using `* *`

Comment: I agree with the comment about asterisks as a selector. It seems very expensive for the browser to comb through the DOM and find every block element inside a block element.

Comment: I was looking at `rem` which, of course, exists precisely for this reason. When reading "CSS3", I thought "yeah, right" but evidently [support is fairly good](https://caniuse.com/#search=rem).

Comment: So might it be fair to say something like "using `* * { font-size:1em }` is only necessary if the CSS is sloppy, as defined by careless font-sizing on elements which aren't properly demarcated by a css class" or somesuch? Seems like defining `div` without further qualification to make `font-size` larger (or, really, any property which can grow like opacity or whatever) is dangerous and requires ugly hacks to get around its bad effects. But if you define `div.bigger` to make things bigger, well, then you only get a bigger `div` when you ask for it.